# How to query XML column?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

Hi I am new to XML Datatype. Can someone help me to pick "Yes I am right" from the following XML. Tried many existing sources but of no use.

```
<Names>
  <Name Id="1" Code="NM" Default="true">Yes I am right</Name>
</Names>

select column.value('(/languages/language/@code)[1]','varchar')
from table t with(nolock)
```

I tried the above code after searching many sources but I am getting an error

```
Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XQuery table.column.value()]: Syntax error near '[', expected a step expression.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for your example would be /Names/Name and the value methods requires that you specify that it is a single value being returned so the complete query would be

```
select column.value('(/Names/Name)[1]','varchar(max)') from t
```

Notice the varchar(max) since otherwise you would just return a single character by specifying varchar without a size.

Comment: Thank you very much for your handy help.